# Putting rectangles into a single image, while saving space

Tags: image

Given an array of rectangles, what would be the algorithm to put them all into a smallest single image, saving as much space as possible but not overlapping the individual smaller images?

I'm asking for the purpose of automatically creating a CSS Spritesheet for use in JavaScript, and likely I'll be doing it in PHP GD; spritesheets save time by reducing the number of HTTP connections that need to be opened up. Here's an example spritesheet, albeit it doesn't seem to save every pixel of available space. Thanks!

[image]